# Slicknav appearing in duplicate on blog

Tags: jquery, slicknav

On my blog page of this in-progress site — http://gratzergraphics.com/clients/ggllc/blog/ — the Slicknav menu appears twice. I cannot figure out why or how to get rid of the duplicate. It's only like this on the blog.

Comment: Next time make sure you mention that this is a mobile issue =) If you click that on desktop you'll never see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

On your blog page you are initializing slick using the `$('nav')`, which is right. However, I see on your blog page that on line 184 you also have another `<nav>` tag:

```
<nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">
 <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Posts navigation</h2>
 <div class="nav-links"><span class='page-numbers current'><span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">Page </span>1</span>
    <a class='page-numbers' href='http://gratzergraphics.com/clients/ggllc/blog/page/2/'><span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">Page </span>2</a>
    <span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>
    <a class='page-numbers' href='http://gratzergraphics.com/clients/ggllc/blog/page/7/'><span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">Page </span>7</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://gratzergraphics.com/clients/ggllc/blog/page/2/">Next page</a></div>
</nav>
```

So it looks like since you have 2 `<nav>` tags in there and you are using `$('nav')` as your selector, you're seeing 2 instances of the plugin. You can either get rid of that or just target the slick nav with a class or an ID. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for forgetting to mention it was on mobile only.